# Mouse double click and ctrl+A not working

Tags: 12.04, updates

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04, and worked fine until I updated some packages it suggested in the update manager after which the double click and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> are not working.
Does any body know the reason of the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Is it possible to mention the list of packages that were updated, or at least the major ones among them?

Comment: I don't know what are the packages exactly, i have updated just the   suggestions from the update icon on the left bar.

Comment: "*I don't know what are the packages exactly,*" ... look inside `/var/log/apt/history.log`. That may tell you.

Comment: I think when i have changed the theme this problems occurred. ctrl+A worked fine after i change the theme keybinding to default, but double click is still not working.